# How to get the cluster numbers for each data point when using dendrogram function MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to know if there are commands to get the cluster to which  a data point belongs to while generating dendrogram.

For example, if the datapoints 32,46,26,15,33,54,17,19,27 are grouped as one cluster, how to obtain this information while plotting dendrogram.

I computed the linkage function and plotted the dendrogram using the command:

`[H,T,perm]=dendrogram(Z,0)` (Since I have more than 30 data points)

Any suggestions on how to extract the cluster information for the example mentioned above will be helpful.

I would like to use the cluster information for visualization purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `dendrogram` generates the dendrogram plot and (as the documentation explains) "returns T, a vector of size M that contains the leaf node number for each object in the original dataset."

If you want to find all elements belonging to cluster `iclust`, you can try something similar to the following:

```
iclust=2; % find all elements in cluster # 2 for example
ifound = find(T==iclust);
```

*edit*

By the way if you want to colorize the dendrogram you can try

```
[H, T] = dendrogram(Z,'colorthreshold',thresh);
```

where `thresh` is a threshold below which branches should be colored.

Comment: Thank you, I could get the cluster information using the find function.
Additionally, I tried counting the number of dendrograms and then used the command 
   
`T=cluster(linkage,'maxclust',threshold)'

Comment: @user1214208 If your answer is better than mine you are actually free to post an answer to your own question!